# AWS SDK NodeJS - Change ECS Fargate Service AutoScaling minimun tasks

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

All good?

My project demands a lot at a certain time of day.
Ex: 7:00AM to 1:00PM

So I need to change the code of the minimum autoscaling tasks of my service, ecs, of aws via aws-sdk, but I can only change the "Desired tasks" via SDK.

It even works, but after about 7 minutes the autoscaling policies end up removing the tasks and overriding what I requested via aws-sdk.

My idea is at this specific time to always leave 10 tasks running without any crashing and then autoscaling can start working again by removing them.

[image]

this is my current code that only changes the desired tasks:

```
static setMinTasks = async (minTasks: number) => {
    const ecs = new AWS.ECS({ apiVersion: '2014-11-13', region: process.env.AWS_REGION })

    const params: AWS.ECS.UpdateServiceRequest = {
        cluster: process.env.AWS_ECS_CLUSTER,
        service: process.env.AWS_ECS_SERVICE,
        desiredCount: minTasks,
        forceNewDeployment: true,
    }

    const ret = await ecs.updateService(params).promise()

    return ret
}
```

[image]

Can you help me with this?